# Table Entity not preseved

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

For data inserted into Azure Table Storage, how do you ensure same data type is returned by querying it? For instance using [Azure Storage SDK for Node.js](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/), if you do `insertEntity()` to insert the following data:

```
{
  PartitionKey: { _: 'the-primary-key', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  RowKey: { _: 'the-row-key', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  jsNum1: { _: 1, '$': 'Edm.Double' },
  jsNum2: { _: 1.1, '$': 'Edm.Double' }
}
```

and retrieve the same data using `queryEntities()`, you get:

```
{
  PartitionKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: 'the-primary-key' },
  RowKey: { '$': 'Edm.String', _: 'the-row-key' },
  Timestamp: { '$': 'Edm.DateTime', _: 2016-07-20T09:47:24.428Z },
  jsNum1: { _: '1.0' },
  jsNum2: { _: 1.1 },
  '.metadata': { etag: 'W/"datetime\'2016-07-20T09%3A47%3A24.4285502Z\'"' }
}
```

Although `jsNum1` and `jsNum2` are inserted as `Edm.Double` the query returns:

- `typeof jsNum1._` is `'string'`
- `typeof jsNum2._` is `'number'`

Since `Edm.Double` is specified during insert, shouldn't `jsNum1._` and `jsNum2._` be the same types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which version of the azure-storage module are you using. This issue has been fixed in the latest version. Please check out the GitHub issue of azure-storage-node repo. https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/40

Comment: I'm using npm module `azure` version `0.10.6` which contains `azure-storage` version `0.3.3`.

Comment: After using `azure-storage ver1.1.0`, `jsNum1._` is no longer a string. `jsNum1: { '$': 'Edm.Double', _: 1 }` and `jsNum2:{ _: 1.1 }`

Comment: I'm curious to understand why `jsNum2` is `{ _: 1.1 }`. Shouldn't it be `jsNum2:{ '$': 'Edm.Double', _: 1.1 }` similar to `jsNum1: { '$': 'Edm.Double', _: 1 }`?

Comment: It's because that 1.1 in JavaScript is enough to indicate it's a double value. 1 will be automatically be treated as integer.

Comment: IMO it would have been easier to manage if `$: 'Edb.Double'` was explicitly specified with `_: 1.1`

Comment: Besides, if `1.1` doesn't require `$: 'Edm.Double'` the same argument should also stand for `1` not requiring `Edm.Double` because JavaScript has just `number`, no `double` or `float`.